# Image Not Fit in React-native

Tags: react-native

To Set an Image in My View.

```
...

<View style={{ flex:1 }}>
  <Image 
    style={{ width:50, height:50 }} 
    source={ require('./mytage') } 
    resizeMode={'cover'} /> 
</View>

...
```

[image]

How Can I fit This Image Properly .

Comment: Can you show your some code snippet?

Comment: Yeah This Is My COde

<View style={{flex:1}}>
<Image style={{width:50, height:50}}  source={require('./mytage)}resizeMode='cover' ></Image>
</View>

Comment: Hi , Can you add your snippet on your question like another question. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using resize mode use width and height with responsive dimensions width and height in percentage.
Like:-

for this you need a package named responsive dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

use `resizeMode='contain'` as cover the image will be as large as possible but contain will fit in acontainer

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
   <Image style={{width:50, height:50}}
   source={require('./mytage)}
   resizeMode='contain' /> // use resizeMode contain also image is self closing
</View>
```